# Launching Activity from another App? (with AndroidAnnotations)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-annotations

How can i launch an AndroidAnnotations Activity_ inside of an App (main)
since external Activity (another App).

this is my current code:

```
Intent codeScannerActivity = new Intent(PACKAGE, CODE_SCANNER_ACTIVITY);
codeScannerActivity.putExtra("codeScannerType", CameraUtils.CODE_SCANNER_SINGLE);
startActivityForResult(codeScannerActivity, Core.ActivityResult.RequestCode.CODE_SCANNER);
```

where **PACKAGE** = "main.app.package"

and **CODE_SCANNER_ACTIVITY** = PACKAGE + ".activity.MyActivity_"

but logs throws:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=**main.app.package** dat=**main.app.package.activity.MyActivity_** (has extras) }

Activity is defined in the Manifest's Main App with the Class "etc.MyActivity_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating wrong the Intent, this is the right way:

```
Intent codeScannerActivity = new Intent();
codeScannerActivity.setComponent(new ComponentName(PACKAGE, CODE_SCANNER_ACTIVITY));
codeScannerActivity.putExtra("codeScannerType", CameraUtils.CODE_SCANNER_SINGLE);
startActivityForResult(codeScannerActivity, Core.ActivityResult.RequestCode.CODE_SCANNER);
```

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you figure out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing the `Intent` incorrectly. For the constructor you are using, the first parameter is interpreted as an "action" and the second as a URI. The error says that there is no activity which can respond to the action "main.app.package" and the URI "main.app.package.activity.MyActivity_".

To fix the problem, first read [Starting Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) and the [Intent javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) from the Android Developer site. Especially look at the documentation for the available constructors. There might be one more appropriate for your purposes than the one you are trying to use. The Intent documentation has a list of standard Activity actions. If you want to start a specific activity, you should use [`Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class<?>)):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.app.package.activity.MyActivity_.class);
```

Comment: in part, u have reason, but yout did not provided the solution, i updated the question with the solution.